# If I don't put my widget into variable it wouldn't be showed PyQt 5 and PyQt 6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt6

I create class `Calculator` and extend it from `QWidget`. If I wrote this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app: QtWidgets.QApplication = QtWidgets.QApplication(System.argv)
    window = Calculator()
    window.show()
    System.exit(app.exec_())
```

widget will be showed and I can use it. But I make it without additional variable:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app: QtWidgets.QApplication = QtWidgets.QApplication(System.argv)
    Calculator().show()
    System.exit(app.exec_())
```

If I run this code widget will be showed for a moment and hide, but program will steel be running after hiding.

Can anybody explain me, Why does it works this way?

Comment: Because the window will be garbage-collected, just like any other object that no longer has a reference. If you wrote `[].append(1)`, what would you expect to happen to the list?

Comment: Python uses a garbage collection system: when an object is created it has a *reference* count based on names that are used to access it (or by adding to other objects, such as a list). If the overall reference count reaches 0, meaning that *absolutely no reference* to that object exists, the object is automatically destroyed. The `Calculator()` instance is just created but *never referenced*, it still can execute its `show()` method (since it's called against that instance) and that's why you can see it for a moment, but after then the object is immediately destroyed.

Comment: But if i wrote `gc.disable()` before this block of code it doesn't attempt any changes. Can you explain me why ?